# Click a button on an MS Access form from C# using Access Interop

Tags: c#, ms-access

I can connect to the access database and run functions etc from c#, I can even get a hold of the button I need to click, but I can't make it think it's been clicked.

```
 nonManagedDb.DoCmd.OpenForm("frmMaintenance", Access.AcFormView.acNormal, MissingVal, Access.AcFormOpenDataMode.acFormReadOnly, Access.AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal, MissingVal);
            var RunRep = (CommandButton)nonManagedDb.Forms["frmMaintenance"].Controls["btnDailySheetsReport"];
```

That's as afar as I've gotten with this, I've tried reflection to grab it's event and invoke it but it's classed as a COM object only so that's out.

Comment: Explain what it is you're trying to do, as opposed to asking us to fix the solution you already know doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Access we can call a procedure in another form using the following syntax:

```
Call Forms.TransactionTotals.UpdateEmployeeHours
```

or

```
Call Forms.OtherTransactionsEntry_VendorInvoices.SetInvoiceID(Me.cboVendorInvoiceID)
```

Now I doubt you can use similar syntax in .Net but maybe that's enough to figure things out via Interop, etc.

Otherwise if you can run a function then create a one line function in Access whose only job is to call the procedure on a form.

Also a click procedure will be called something like

```
cmdDeleteTransaction_Click
```